# collection_select throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, select

I have a select box on a form to select the type of category for a project:

`<%= f.select(:category, collection_select(:project_category, :cat_id, @project_category, :id, :cat_name)) %>`

It should populate from the `project_categories` table.

The migration looks like this:

```
class CreateProjectCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :project_categories do |t|
      t.string    :category_name
      t.text      :cat_desc
      t.date      :created_on
      t.datetime  :updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

My `project.rb` model deines `has_one :category` and the `projectCategory.rb` model defines `belongs_to :project`.

My `project_categories` table is populated with data.  I got the syntax from the Rails Guides, but it's not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the wrong syntax.  The final code looks like this:

`<%= collection_select(:project_categories, :id, Project_Category.all, :id, :category_name) %>`

Essentially the syntax should be defined like this: WARNING: PSEUDO-CODE!!

`<%= collection_select(:database_table, :lookup_value, Model_Name.all, :returned_numeric_value, :returned_text_value_based_on_numeric_value) %>`

Don't know why the API docs couldn't have just *said* so...